# Every linear application is sum of linear applications of rank 1

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $V$ and $W$ finite dimensional vectorial spaces over a field $\mathbb{K}$. I must prove that every linear application from $V$ to $W$ is sum of linear applications of rank $1$.

The suggestion given states that just fixed a basis of the image and we consider the projections on the lines generated by a single basis element.

I can't understand how this is true, could someone explain it to me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{e_i\}$ be a basis of $V$ and let $T$ be a linear application $T:V\to W$.  Then for any $v=x_1e_1+\dots x_ne_n$ you have
$$
Tv=x_1T(e_1)+\dots x_nT(e_n).
$$
The applications $T_i$ that send $v$ to $x_iT(e_i)$ have rank one, since their images are the spans of $T(e_i)$. So you have $T=T_1+T_2+\dots +T_n$ where each $T_i$ has rank one.

Another way to look at this: every matrix is the sum of matrices containing one of the columns of the original and zeroes in the remaining positions. These clearly have rank one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in this case you have not chosen a basis for the image, but only a system of generators for the image, is that okay?